# Change cursor-type in MinTTY

Tags: terminal-emacs, cursor

I'd like terminal Emacs to observe the current value of `cursor-style` when the current terminal emulator supports commands to change the cursor.

For example: [`MinTTY`](https://code.google.com/p/mintty/) is the default terminal emulator for Cygwin. According to [this page](https://code.google.com/p/mintty/wiki/Tips#Mode-dependent_cursor_in_vim), it supports changing cursor styles using the following escape sequences:

- `\e[1 q` for a block cursor.
- `\e[5 q` for a bar cursor.

Other terminal emulators that support these escapes include the VTE-based emulators (`gnome-terminal` and friends) and `xterm` and its derivatives.

Currently, hacks exist for [`evil-mode`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14929/how-do-i-set-cursor-colours-per-evil-state-in-the-non-gui-text-terminal?lq=1) that attempt to simulate this support. Unfortunately, these break when the terminal doesn't support said escapes. [Here's a question to see if that's fixable](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19040/send-string-to-terminal-but-hide-output/19043?noredirect=1#comment28715_19043).

As far as I can tell, Emacs doesn't support changing the cursor natively. Is there any way we can support it without relying on a package like `evil`?

Comment: Do you want to change the cursor type globally, or to obey `cursor-type` in the current buffer? AFAIK Emacs doesn't support changing the cursor type according to the current buffer on text terminals, but you can set `visible-cursor` to switch between two cursors globally (I don't know whether that toggles between block and bar, but that could be changed in terminfo).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set cursor colours per evil-state in the (non-GUI) text terminal?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14929/how-do-i-set-cursor-colours-per-evil-state-in-the-non-gui-text-terminal)

Comment: @Gilles I just discovered that this has already been solved by a package: `evil-terminal-cursor-changer` Unfortunately, said package is broken, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I don't think that question is a duplicate. While there may be solutions that work for both, the problems are pretty different. You might find a Mintty-specific solution; the other question might have an evil-specific solution. Were you specifically interested in changing the cursor according to the mode in evil? That's not what you asked here…

Comment: If you clarify your question, someone may well find a solution that works for you. For one thing, the control sequences that Emacs sends to the terminal aren't hardcoded; if it's sending the wrong ones, that's fixable. It's only if it sends nothing for the event when you want to change the cursor type that you have a difficult problem, and even for that there might be a workaround.