# send-string-to-terminal but hide output

Tags: terminal-emacs

I'd like to send some commands to the terminal Emacs is running in, using `send-string-to-terminal`. However, some terminals don't support the command I have in mind.

When this is the case, the command is echoed after the cursor, temporarily overwriting the display, and causing graphical corruption:

**Result of running <kbd>M-:</kbd>`(send-string-to-terminal "\e[5 q")` in `xfce4-terminal`**

[image]

(Note that the text appears in the echo area by mere coincidence—if I had run the code using a keybinding in a different buffer, the output would be positioned after the cursor)

Obviously, this is not desirable. Is there a way to hide the output (or mask it by redrawing the display in that region) so the command can silently fail?

Comment: Try (redisplay t) or (force-window-update).

Comment: Try `(message)` or `(message "")` to clear the echo area.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>You may temporarily replace the `message` function, which does the actual job of displaying the string in the echo area :</strike>

```
(cl-letf (((symbol-function 'message) #'ignore))
  (send-string-to-terminal "\e[5 q"))
```

`ignore` takes an arbitrary number of arguments, does nothing and returns nil.

---

**EDIT**

I misunderstood the question's meaning. It turns out, after looking a bit at the [`send-string-to-terminal` function definition](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/src/dispnew.c#L5575) in Emacs' C source, there is no way to prevent it from echoing the supplied command.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help. `message` isn't actually used in `send-string-to-terminal`, so there's no effect. Furthermore, the output doesn't always occur in the minibuffer. As I stated, it occurs after the cursor. It's placement in the minibuffer is merely a side-effect of my using the minibuffer to call the code.

Comment: Oops :) I updated my answer with relevant info.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll add some more info to the question so nobody else gets confused.